# How can I load a default language plist if the localized version does not exist for the current language?

Tags: objective-c, ios, localization, plist

I am loading the plist like so:

```
 NSString * plistPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Names" ofType:@"plist"];
 NSDictionary * contentArray = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:plistPath];
```

But contentArray is nil if the plist doesn't exist for the current device's language. How can I default to English?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NSBundle` effectively uses the [`CFBundleDevelopmentRegion`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/CoreFoundationKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-130430) (aka "Localization native development region") entry in the application/bundle's `Info.plist` file to specify the "fallback" language, if you will.

For example, let's assume we have the following bundle layout:

```
MyApp.app
 // no Numbers.plist here
.....
en.lproj/
    Numbers.plist // english-version
es.lproj/
    Numbers.plist // spanish-version
```

And, the Info.plist specifies a `CFBundleDevelopmentRegion` of `en`.

If a French user runs the app, and there is no localized `Numbers.plist` file for `fr`, then `NSBundle` should return the `Numbers.plist` file in the `en.lproj` directory.