# Defaulting Locale on iPhone (en_NZ to en_AU)

Tags: ios, locale, nslocalizedstring

I've got an iOS app where I need to use the same resources for the en_NZ (New Zealand) localization as the en_AU (Australian) localization.

Instead of duplicating my resource files is there a way I can make it so if somebody with a locale of en_NZ uses the app it will default to the en_AU resources?

Comment: This could be what your looking for http://stackoverflow.com/a/13017789/786845

Comment: So does this mean in an en_NZ info plist I specify en_AU as a native dev region?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1) Get lang

```
    NSUserDefaults* apple_defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
    NSArray* languagesList = [apple_defaults objectForKey: @"AppleLanguages"];
    NSString* lang = [languagesList objectAtIndex: 0];
```

2) Then convert him

```
    if ([lang isEqualToString:@"en_NZ"])
    {
        lang = @"en_AU";
    }
```

And you can use **lang** for your app as **en_AU** instead **en_NZ**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following approach:
1) Create en_AU resources
2) check if your current locale is en_NZ

```
NSString *currentLanguage = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
// or 
NSString *langID = [[NSLocale preferredLanguages] objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *lang = [[NSLocale currentLocale] displayNameForKey:NSLocaleLanguageCode value:langID];

NSBundle *xBundle;
```

3) in case en_NZ:

```
// find the path to the bundle based on the locale
NSString *bundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Localizable" ofType:@"strings" inDirectory:nil forLocalization:@"en_AU"];

// load it!
xBundle = [[NSBundle alloc] initWithPath:[bundlePath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]];
```

4) in case other than en_NZ:

```
xBundle = nil;
```

5) use in your code:

```
NSLocalizedStringFromTableInBundle(@"yourStr2Localize", nil, xBundle, nil);
```