# iOS - After changing the language does not apply default

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization

I have two languages in my app, English - default and Swedish. When it is Swedish and I switch to the another (Ukrainian, Spanish) should go to the default - English, but still Swedish.

Comment: You mean you switch the device language to another?

Comment: And what is the preffered language order in the language & region settings?

Comment: Possible dublication of http://stackoverflow.com/a/13017789/4611751

Comment: @user3581248 Ukrainian, Swedish, English. Do you think, it looks first in preferred, and then the language which by default?

Comment: I guess it won't hurt to try putting Swedish below English in the preferred list. However I am not 100% sure that this is the cause.

Comment: Thank you very much, you helped me!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answers, first of all, your device looks at **preferred language order** and then at **default language** in a project.